# Build several javascript files into one (require.js or something else)

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

My javascript project looks like this (**Example A**)

```
;(function (window, document, undefined) {

    var func1 = function () {
        // some code
    };

    var func2 = function () {
        // some code
    };

    // ... some more functions

    // lines of main code
    // ...

})(window, document);
```

I want to place func1, func2, ..., code in separate files to make code like this (**Example B**):

```
;(function (window, document, undefined) {

    var func1 = require ("func1.js");
    var func2 = require ("func2.js");
    // ... more requires


    // lines of main code
    // ...

})(window, document);
```

…and then somehow compile it to get the code as in Example A

Is there any particular way to do this? I tried to use require.js (*r.js*), but i've got `require` and `define` statements in compiled code (so I need require.js to run compiled code in browser). Is it possible to get flat static js-file without any dependencies with r.js? Maybe there is another way to do this? Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your code works, you can always just go `cat *.js > all.js` then run a minifier or something on it.

Comment: Good idea, but i want to include my submodules exactly in the scope where they required. Not just  copy some files into one